# Gcloud Datastore query geospatial

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

How do I run query geospatial in a Google Cloud Datastore database use Node.JS?

I have records with geopoint type fields:

```
"location": {
  "latitude": -3.7697645,
  "longitude": -38.4755724 
}
```

I already consulted the documentation and could not find it.